# All Makefiles broken

Tags: make, makefile

I can't run any Makefiles anymore.
I get:

```
./Makefile: line 1: sorter:: command not found
```

Content of Makefile:

```
sorter: sorter.o
    gcc sorter.o -o sorter

sorter.o: sorter.c
    gcc -c sorter.c

test:
    ./run_test

check:
    c_style_check sorter.c

clean:
    rm -f sorter *.o
```

What's surprising is that all my Makefiles used to run fine just yesterday. I don't know what happened, I think my Lubuntu had an update but that was it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is occurring because you are expecting your shell to understand and run the file.

Makefiles aren't meant to be executable - they're given as inputs to the `make` command e.g. `make -f Makefile` - or just `make`, since it will search the current directory for a file with default names like `Makefile`, `makefile`.

From `man make`:

```
   To  prepare to use make, you must write a file called the makefile that
   describes the relationships among files in your program, and the states
   the  commands for updating each file.  In a program, typically the exe‐
   cutable file is updated from object files, which are in  turn  made  by
   compiling source files.

   Once  a  suitable  makefile  exists,  each  time you change some source
   files, this simple shell command:

          make

   suffices to perform all necessary  recompilations.   The  make  program
   uses  the  makefile  description and the last-modification times of the
   files to decide which of the files need to be  updated.   For  each  of
   those files, it issues the commands recorded in the makefile.

   make  executes  commands  in  the makefile to update one or more target
   names, where name is typically a program.  If no -f option is  present,
   make  will  look for the makefiles GNUmakefile, makefile, and Makefile,
   in that order.
```

Comment: That being said, you can use a shebang for makefiles to make them behave like executables: `#!/usr/bin/make -f`